# Офіційні назви кольорів

Tags: терміни, прикметники, складні-прикметники

Насамперед мене бентеже сполука *іменника* і *прикметника*.

Наприклад [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2), без джерел, наводе сполуки виду:

1. **Прикметник** + **іменник**, *steel blue* як *синя сталь*. При цьому на просторах щодо кольору можна зустрїти наприклад [*сталь синя*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&lr=-lang_ru), [*золото старе*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%22), шчо схоже на випадок з біолоґією: [*гуска сіра*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0) і [*ворона чорна*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0), через шчо можлива плутанина.
2. **Прикметник** + **прикметник**, *аndroid green* як *андроїдний зелений*. По сутї, прямий переклад з Анґлійської.
3. **Прикметник** + **родовий іменник**, *Brandeis blue* як *блакитний Брандейса*. Зручно проти *Брандейський блакитний*, тобто коли власні назви.
4. **Складений через дефіс**, *amaranth pink* як *амарантово-рожевий*. Короше за повну форму, але його не всюди застосувати чи менш естетичне, коли прикметників більше за двох.

Помітно, же для анґлійської то просто<sup>*</sup> іменник як **прикметник** і **прикметник**. Також подеколи є записи через дефіс як *violet-eggplant*.

* переважно, бо подеколи є явне перетвореня до прикметника за допомогою наростка наприклад *-ian* як в *Persian blue*. Правда, і тут можна посперечати ся і тлумачити як іменник: *блакитний персів*.

Візьму до прикладу [*Mars red*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mars-red), з котрого можна зустрїти переклади як: [*марсіанський червоний*](https://yunata.032.ua/news/105385), [*Марс червоний*](https://decorashop.com.ua/tovary-dlia-khudozhnykiv-i-dekoratoriv/farby-akrylovi/farba-akrylova-acrilico-mars-chervonyi.html), [*червоний Марс*](https://uk.p-advice.com/color-theory-know-your-reds), [*марсово-червоний*](https://uk.venicebiennalesiria.com/254-best-wallet-cases-for-iphone-8-plus-in-2021).

Якшчо брати за найпростїшою уніфікацію, то для мене най-красшим способом буде другий. Але то суто для мене. Тож чи є десь офіційний перелік кольорів чи поради?

Comment: 2-ге і 3-тє — це, на мій погляд майже те саме, лише питання смаку й милозвучності (андроїдний зелений vs. зелений «Адроїда», Брандейсів (брандейсівський) блакитний vs. блакитний Брайдеса). Тобто, по-моєму, суттєві варіанти — це 1-й, 2-й (≈3-й) і 4-й.

Comment: Зауважу стосовно 1-го — порівняння з біологією є дещо помилковим, адже у латині іменник передує прикметнику, а в англійській навпаки. Steel blue — це сталевий синій, тобто це словосполучення радше пасує до 2-го.

Comment: Відгук про нові мітки. Це питаннє не про переклад [особїво з анґлійської]. Також не зовсїм про прикметники, але най будить.

Comment: Android Green — це колір зеленого робота Android, який є логотипом операційної системи Android від Google. Коректним перекладом буде "зелений Андроїд". https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/brand-guidelines

Answer (score 4):

Натрапив на невеличкий — менше 100 сторінок — діяспорський словник: [Англійсько-український словник назв кольорів і кольорознавства](//diasporiana.org.ua/slovniki-dovidniki/vovk-a-anglijsko-ukrayinskyj-slovnyk-nazv-koloriv-i-koloroznavstva/) ([Анатоль Вовк](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), редактор Богдан Струмінський), 1986 рік.

> **steel blue** noun and adjective «сталѐвосі́рий» колір, опис: (в середньому) сіря́воси́ній [1, 4], ясноблакитний [4], сѝнюватостале́вий [П].

Лише це слово зі згаданих в запитаннї було. Втім, словник має додатки з описами і свою систему *УНК* — *універсальне назовництво кольорів*, що основана на американській *Universal Color Language*, тобто *UCL*. Раджу ознайомити ся. Там також є роздїл з назвою *правопис складених назв кольорів*, котрого і витягну сюди…

---

**Правопис складених назв кольорів**

У проблемі писання складених слів (сукупно чи з розділкою) «Харківський правопис» радив «оглядатися на **наголос**», а саме в словах з одних наголосом писати складники разом (напр. жовтогарячий), а з розділкою писати слова з двома наголосами (напр. сільсько-господарський) (Б-12, стор. 85). Цей критерій, одначе, недостатній, бо є численні випадки, де кількість наголосів неясна чи непевна.

Тому в словнику ми застосували **семантичний критерій** писання складених назв, як більше надійний. Згідно з ним таку назву пишемо з розділкою (дефісом), якщо обидва складники рівнорядні, але пишемо її вкупі, якщо один член назви тільки модифікує другий, тобто він йому підпорядкований, а тим самим він з ним нерівнорядний. (Пропозиція редактора словника).

До складених назв кольорів з рівнорядними складниками належать ті, що стосуються дво або більше незмішаних, **суміжних** кольорів (назви, що відносяться до двобарвности або різнобарвности), напр., **чорно-білий**, **синьо-жовтий**, **червоно-біло-синій**.

До нерівнорядних, підпорядкованих складників у назвах кольорів зараховуємо ті, що проходять від слів, які визначають ясноту кольору: **блідий**, **ясний**, **помірний**, **темний** або його інтенсивність (насиченість): **сірявий**, **брудний**, **помірний**, **густий**, **яскравий**, **ярий**.

Також нерівнорядно складеними вважаємо назви одностайних проміжних між головними, кольорів таких, як **жовтозелений** (к. середній між жовтим і зеленим) та **жовтавозелений** (зелений к. з домішкою жовтого). Тому, що це правило веде до деяких довгих назв, для допомоги в читанні даємо при таких словах головний (´) та допоміжний (`) наголоси, напр., брунатнува̀тооли́вковий, червона̀вофія́лковий.

Врешті нерівнорядно складеними є слова, в яких наявне порівнанна (метафора), напр. **сніжнобілий** (білий, як сніг), небесноблакитний (блакитний, як небеса) та полумʼяночервоний (червоний неначе полумʼя).

Тому, що в правописі складених назв кольорів наявні різниці в правописних словниках (А-11, А-13, А-27) і в правописних довідниках (Б-6, Б-12), а знову ж у термонологічних словниках «Золотої доби» української термінології (1923-1932 рр.) знаходимо численні правописні непослідовності, наша система є спробою цю ділянку правопису усистематизувати. У менше повній формі ця система вжита також в *Українському правописі* П. Ковалева (Б-6).

---

Нажаль, нічого про порядок не сказано. Але можна помітити, що зазвичай складений прикметник без дефіса або, що рїдше, прикметник + іменник кольора. Для прикладу наведу дві статтї також:

> **Pompeian red** noun «помпейська червінь», «помпѐйськочерво́ний», опис: червоний (помі́рний або сірявий) [2]; сірий черво̀ноора́нжовий або ясний червона̀вобруна́тний [4].

> **Prussian blue** noun and adjective «пруська синь», колір «пруськосиній», берлінський лазу́р [П, С] (колір піґменту), опис: синій (помі́рний або си́льний) або блакитний (темний або густий) [2, 3, 4]; яскра̀воси́ній або блакитний [С].

---

**Домовленості**

« » — слова в таких лапках є дослівним перекладом англійської назви, невживаним, одначе, у мововжитку

**Значення кодів джерел у реєстрі словника**

[1] Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 17)
[2] American Heritage Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 1)
[3] Oxford Illustrated Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 13)
[4] Dictionary of Color Names (Підрозділ В. ч. 10)
[П] Подвезко і Балла, **Англо-український словник**, (Підрозділ А. ч. 25)
[С] **Словник української мови**, 11 томів (Підрозділ А. ч. 5)

**Джерела і література до теми**

(А-11) Головащук, С. І. та ін. **Орфографічний словник української мови**. Київ, в-во «Наукова думка», 1975.
(А-13) Голоскевич, Г. **Правописний словник**. 8-ме вид. Нью-Йорк, вид. А. Білоуса, 1952.
(А-27) Рудницький, Яр. і Церкевич, К., ред. **Правописний словник української мови**. Нью-Йорк і Монтреаль, УММАН і НДТУМ, 1979.
(Б-6) Ковалів, П. **Український правопис**. 2-ге вид. Нью-Йорк, Інст. Укр. Мови, 1977.
(Б-12) **Український правопис**. 1-ше вид. Харків, ДВУ, 1929.

Comment: Гм… Тобто, якщо я правильно розумію, вони радять писати «синьозелений», коли мова, наприклад, про однотонний об'єкт проміжного кольору між синім і зеленим (зелений з нотками синяви), але «синьо-зелений», коли, наприклад, об'єкт чітко двобарвний, тобто поверхня складається з окремих синіх і зелених фрагментів? Це дуже логічно, але от чи дійсно розділятимуть це люди на практиці…

Answer (score 2):

Як я вже писав у коментарі, я не бачу принципової різниці між 2-м та 3-м (як на мене це питання лише смаку та милозвучності: андроїдний зелений vs. зелений «Адроїда», Брандейсів (брандейсівський) блакитний vs. блакитний Брайдеса), відповідно лишаються 1-й, 2-й (≈3-й) і 4-й.

Я не знаю щодо офіційних/стандартних назв, але, по-моєму, всі три способи мають право на існування і я не бачу причин звужувати вибір (усі три способи доречні, але частково в різних випадках).

1-й спосіб (синя сталь, рожевий персик, блакитне небо) — це формально не назви кольорів (адже сталь — це матеріал, персик — це плід тощо). Якщо контекст задано, то ці словосполучення застосовні; або ж контекст можна явно задати, додавши слово *колір* — «спідниця кольору синьої сталі», «автомобіль кольору рожевого персика», хоча це дещо довго/одноманітно; але поза контекстом використання такого способу може мати недолугий чи навіть неграмотний вигляд. Перевагою цього способу є те, що ми як завгодно точно означувати колір, не обмежуючи кількість слів (кольору стиглого рожевого персика, що так добре визрів під лагідними променями сонця одеського лану). Коротко: «+» — можна описувати колір як завгодно точно чи поетично; «−» — поза контекстом формально нелогічне, а явне додавання слова *колір* робить фрази довшими/одноманітнішими.

2-й (3-й) спосіб (Брандейсів блакитний або блакитний Брандейса) — це вже зазначення кольору (на «персиковий рожевий» уже неможливо заперечити, мовляв, персик — це плід, а не колір). Але ми все ще не завжди можемо використовувати такі означення в реченні без слова *колір* (а іноді навіть і з ним не можемо): у словосполученні «доларовий зелений светр» обидва прикметника (і *доларовий*, і *зелений*) стосуватимуться іменника (тобто виходитиме *доларовий светр*, а не *доларовий зелений*). Також цей спосіб дає дещо менші засоби для уточнення, ніж попередній. Отже: «±» — формально коректне, але використовувати в реченні без слова *колір* все ще не завжди можливо; «±» — порівняно високі можливості для вточнювання, але граматично ми все-таки обмеженіші, ніж у 1-му способі.

4-й спосіб з погляду граматики, наскільки я знаю (виправте мене, будь ласка, якщо я помиляюся), накладає жорткі обмеження. Річ у тім, що дефіс у, наприклад, «жовто-зелений стіл» позначає, що стіл *і* жовтий, *і* зелений (а не те, що слово *жовтий* є просто вточненням до слова *зелений*). Відповідно ми не можемо написати, наприклад, *брандейсівсько-блакитний* чи *брандейсово-блакитний*, бо формально це означатиме *брандейсів(ський) і блакитний* (а не *по-брандейсівському блакитний*, як нам би хотілося). Хоча це не може виступати аргументом проти інших варіантів написання (якщо не через дефіс, а окремо чи разом: *брандейсівсько блакитний*, *брандейсовоблакитний*), але я не знаю, чи використовуються вони десь; також, можливо, такий спосіб застосовний, коли перша частина хоча б частково має семантику кольору (золотисто-жовтий) або вся пара широковживана. Зате, коли такий спосіб можна застосувати, воно відмінюватиметься як повноцінний прикметник. Отже: «−» — не завжди можна так складати пару; «+» — якщо можна, то результат добре інтегрується будь-куди без додавання слова *колір*.

Answer (score -1):

### Офіційний список кольорів

**[Колір](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80)** — це суб'єктивна характеристика сприйняття світлової хвилі в межах видимого для людського зору діапазону (від 380 до 760 нм). Теоретично людське око здатне розрізняти до 10 мільйонів кольорів, тому список [**широко розповсюджених і використовуваних кольорів**](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2) постійно уточнюється.

**[Основні кольори](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%20%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%86%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC,%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%85%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F%D1%85.)** — кольори, змішуючи які можна отримати всі інші кольори та відтінки.

> В українській термінології основними кольорами спектру називають
> **червоний**, **оранжевий**, **жовтий**, **зелений**, **блакитний**, **синій** та **фіолетовий**.

Втім, проблема відповідності кольорів в українській та англійській термінології ускладнюється тим, що сучасна англійська мова не розрізняє блакитного і синього кольорів, тож обидва позначає кольором blue. Та перекладом позначення синього проблема не обмежується, то ж звідки взялися подвійні назви в англійській мові?

### RGB color model

**RGB** - це адитивна колірна модель, в якій основні кольори світла червоний, зелений та синій складаються у різний спосіб для відтворення широкого спектру кольорів. Колірна модель RGB адитивна у тому сенсі, що коли світлові промені різного кольору (частоти) накладаються у просторі, їх світлові спектри складаються (довжина хвилі до довжини хвилі), утворюючи повний результуючий спектр.

Але пристрої від різних виробників по-різному визначають і відтворюють значення RGB. Тому, щоб визначити яким саме має бути еталонний колір, було створено прив'язку до кольорів, які можна зустріти в фізичному світі і спостерігати неозброєним оком.

**Persian blue** (перський блакитний) - це колір мінералу лазурит, яким традиційно вкривають крівлі мечетей на Близькому Сході та прикрашають керамічні вироби.

**Mars red** (червоний Марс) - колір ідентичний до брудної іржі, яка утворюється внаслідок окислення заліза. У великій кількості іржу можна спостерігати в атмосфері планети Марс.

**[Steel blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_blue)** (сталевий синій) — це відтінок синього кольору, який нагадує блакитну сталь, тобто сталь, яка була піддана вороненню для захисту від іржі. Це один із найменш яскравих відтінків синього, його зазвичай ідентифікують як синьо-сірий колір.

**[Pompeian red](https://maggiemaggio.com/color/2010/10/pompeian-red/)** (помпейський червоний), **[Prussian blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue)** (пруський синій) і т.д.

### Система підбору кольорів Pantone

**Pantone** — це стандартизована система підбору кольорів для відтворення за допомогою друку. Вона набула широкого використання спочатку серед виробників одягу, а потім і графічних дизайнерів, друкарень та і в інших галузях.

Стандартизуючи кольори, різні виробники в різних місцях можуть посилатися на систему Pantone, щоб переконатися, що їх кольори збігаються без прямого контакту з оригінальним. З 2000 року Інститут кольорів Pantone почав оголошувати «Кольори року», завдяки чому став відомим широкому загалу.

### CMYK color model

**Процес CMYK** — це метод кольорового друку за допомогою чотирьох чорнил — блакитного, пурпурового, жовтого та чорного. Більшість друкованих матеріалів у світі виготовляється за допомогою процесу CMYK і існує спеціальна підгрупа кольорів Pantone, які можна відтворити за допомогою CMYK.

Comment: Вибачте, але мені здається, це не відповідає на запитання. (Може, на заголовок, але не на оснавний текст.)

Comment: Всьо так, як написав Саша: не во̂дпове̂дає на запитання. Також очьовидно, що геть не читалиʼсте мого запитання, бо вже згадувавʼем там Вікіпедію, котра _без джерел, наводе_ з тою самою ланкою.

Comment: @Sútnôstj, моя відповідь покликана доповнити вже існуючі від інших учасників, надає відповіді щодо перекладу наведених прикладів з посиланнями на першоджерела та роз'яснює за яким принципом оригінальні кольори отримали свої назви.